# Trying to take data form input and write to specific cell in a specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a simple input form that pulls some display data from a specific worksheet and then outputs / feeds input data which is placed in a text box to a specific sheet and cell reference upon clicking a button.

I keep getting a syntax error when I go to activate the output sheet - I'm new to VB and coding so apologies on the rudimentary question.

Here is the code I'm using for the output.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()     
    activateSheet(Weeklyhours As String)      
    Sheets(Weeklyhours).Select     
    ActiveSheet.Range("I2").Select = TxtMonhours.Text  
    ActiveSheet.Range("j2").Select = TxtTueshours.Text
```

When I run it I am getting a Syntax Error.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot next this `activateSheet(Weeklyhours As String)` in a Sub: what's the intent here?

Answer (score 2):

This line definitely isn't the right syntax.

```
activateSheet(Weeklyhours As String)
```

The only time (I'm aware of) using `As` is in declaration statement

```
dim Weeklyhours as string
```

This might be what you're looking for but it's a little hard to tell what everything is.  You don't have to activate sheets and select cells to modify them.  It's better to not do that whenever you can, which is most of the time.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    sheets("Weeklyhours").range("I2").value = TxtMonHours.text
    sheets("Weeklyhours").range("J2").value = TxtTueshours.text
    'This assumes you have a sheet with the name "Weeklyhours"
end sub
```